# Automate converting labels to annotation in ArcMap at multiple scales?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling, annotation

I need to be able to convert labels to Annotation feature classes at multiple scale levels for both address and street data. Similar in concept to generating tiled layers for a web service, I have 5 to 10 pre-defined extents that I need to export annotation for. The resulting annotation will be used in an ArcEngine application that is restricted to those zoom levels. When done manually, I turn on labels for the layers I want labeled, right-click each layer and choose 'Convert Labels to Annotation, save them to an annotation feature class, then repeat for each scale level. Does anyone know of a way of accomplishing this programmatically? All of my code so far has been in Python, but if necessary I'm open to other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ArcGIS 10, you should be looking at the [Tiled Labels To Annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tiled_Labels_To_Annotation/007000000007000000/) tool.  This tool does what you're looking for (you may need to modify your input extents to have a scale field if they do not have one).  If you're using an earlier release, you can only accomplish this via the ConvertLabelsToAnnotation coclass in ArcObjects.