# Exporting and editing annotation feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, editing, file-geodatabase, annotation

I would like to convert labels to annotations and make some advanced editing for these labels using ArcPy.

How would I do this?

I'm using a file geodatabase and ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these earlier Q&As and a Help page:

1. [Automate converting labels to annotation in ArcMap at multiple scales?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/automate-converting-labels-to-annotation-in-arcmap-at-multiple-scales)
2. [Labeling features and converting them to annotations with ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12059/how-could-i-label-features-and-convert-them-to-annotations-with-arcpy)
   and
3. [Tiled Labels To Annotation (Cartography) methods](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tiled_Labels_To_Annotation/007000000007000000/):

> Converts labels to annotation for layers in a map document based on a
>   polygon index layer.

Comment: thanks a lot Aragon you have helped me a lot :), concerning advanced editing for annotations i have to set the property "Font size" for Example to modify just one annotation.